# How to configure Com+ .net Assembly called from classic ASP to run under AppPool User

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp-classic, com+

I have a very specific scenario: A classic ASP application is running a .Net Assembly through COM+. It's working, but I'm having problems regarding which user the DLL is running under.

In my staging server, both w3wp.exe process and the .net DLL are running under AppPool user : `IIS AppPool\AppPoolName`. But in the production server, w3wp.exe is running under AppPool user, while the .net DLL is running under `NT Authority`. I need it to run under AppPool user so I can configure permissions to a folder the DLL needs to write to.

I discover the user the DLL is running under calling `Environment.UserName` in C# code.

Some things I've already tried and checked:

- My app is running on a custom web site under iis (Not DEfaultWebSite), with its bindings properly configured to http 80.
- The web site is running on a exclusive AppPool.
- The AppPool is configured to Integrated pipeline
- The AppPool is configured to use `Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity`
- IIS \ MyWebSite \ ASP \ ComPlus Properties, the settings on production server are the same than staging server.
- In Task Manager, `w3wp.exe` process is running under AppPool user.